# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: The client area of window of some apps is black while starting

Tags: 18.04, gui, performance

Recently I upgraded my 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. After that I noticed that initialization of some apps (krusader, okular e.g.) takes more time that it took before and while starting the window they show is black. I also noticed that "black window" period is equal for every program having this weird behavior ~25 seconds.

Most of programs start well.

I tried to search the web, but with no success.

Ideas?

**--Update--**

Krusader console output is

```
q@4xybook:~/temp$ krusader 
Icon theme "clear" not found.
Icon theme "clear" not found.
Icon theme "GNOME" not found.
Icon theme "GNOME" not found.
Trying to convert empty KLocalizedString to QString.
Failed to unregister window menu, reason: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply ("Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the old global [app menu extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/). I removed one and installed latest version from https://gitlab.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu. This made things work.

Comment: When you use a gnome shell extension, be sure that this extension is updated to work with the gnome shell version you have. An extension is, like the name, something that extending another thing. As that another thing is the shell, the compatibility between both is really important, and can cause a situations like that.